# PerformancePoint 2007, Planning server configuration error

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, performancepoint

I'm trying to configure the planning server for performancepoint 2007.  I have the database setup on a separate machine on the same network.  Everything seems to validate correctly but on the last step of the configuration screen, when I click "configure", I get this error:

```
Configuration failed.

Error 1:  Windows NT user or group 'DEV-WEB\Administrator' not found. Check the name again.
```

Does anyone know what this error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found documentation online saying that the 2 servers need to be on the same domain or you have to use a trusted domain so the sql server can access the admin console on the other server.